# Remove some elements from python pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet with 20000rows and 5 columns. This dataframe contains several -9 value. I want to delete those -9 without replacing any another value on their place.

Below is the sample dataframe:

```
a   b   c
1   3   -9
-9   2   8
5   -9   -9
-9   0   2
```

I need a data frame that looks like the following:

`a   b   c
 1   3
     2   8
 5
     0   2`

The following is a part of output file:
`23799  1
    11  1.000000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
23800   2
    2   0.100000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
    11  0.900000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
23801   2
    2   0.200000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
    11  0.800000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
23802   2
    2   0.200000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
    11  0.800000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
23803   3
    2   0.600000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
    10  0.100000    0.1 0.173   1   0.827   0.5 0
    11  0.300000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
23804   2
    2   0.400000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
    11  0.600000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
23805   2
    2   0.500000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
    11  0.500000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
23806   3
    5   0.100000    0.1 0.1 1   0.9 0.5 0
    9   0.400000    0.1 0.089   1   0.889   0.5 0.022
    11  0.500000    0.1 0.133   1   0.867   0.5 0
23807   2
    5   0.400000    0.1 0.1 1   0.9 0.5 0
    9   0.600000    0.1 0.089   1   0.889   0.5 0.022
23808   2
    5   0.200000    0.1 0.1 1   0.9 0.5 0
    9   0.800000    0.1 0.089   1   0.889   0.5 0.022`

Comment: It's not clear how the contents of the dataframe maps to the output file you quoted.  Could you please add some explanation?  For example, your example dataframe has only integers, but the output file is full of floats, also the rows seem to be grouped.  It is difficult to understand how the dataframe relates to this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need all rows with at least one value `-9` - filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.ne(-9).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  3
```

**Detail**:

Check if values not equal -9:

```
print (df.ne(-9))
       a      b
0   True   True
1  False   True
2   True  False
3  False  False
```

Check if all Trues per rows:

```
print (df.ne(-9).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Replace to nothing is not possible, need replace by `0` or `NaN` or some value:

```
print (df.replace(-9, np.nan))
     a    b
0  1.0  3.0
1  NaN  2.0
2  5.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```

Only method is reshape - create 2 columns with all numeric in one column by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df1 = df.melt(var_name='A', value_name='B')
df1 = df1[df1['B'] != -9]
print (df1)
    A  B
0   a  1
2   a  5
4   b  3
5   b  2
7   b  0
9   c  8
11  c  2
```

Comment: I have just edited the que. pls see that. I want to remove -9 from excel sheet but also dont want to replace it with a space

Comment: @lsr729 - It is impossible, need replace it by some value like 0 or NaN or space.

Comment: I need that file in .txt as a model input, that model reads a space as a value and gives error.

Comment: @lsr729 - Can you be specific? Because if use some method from `scipy`, it obviously not working with missing values or strings, so replace to NaN or space or some string is not good idea. Need remove these rows or replace to numeric.

Comment: I don't want to remove the rows but cells with -9 value. is there any way to remove -9 values without replacing with anything else?

Comment: @lsr729 - If need 5 columns and `20000` rows not.

Comment: @lsr729 - added one solution, but need reshape data - different format of rows and columns like original.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments to @jezrael's answer, it seems, you want to export the result as a text file (e.g. csv or tsv).  Since you don't intend to work with the dataframe in pandas, I would use a simple `replace`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 3, -9], [-9, 2, 8], [5, -9, -9], [-9, 0, 2]],
    columns=("a", "b", "c"),
)
df.replace(to_replace=-9, value='')
  .to_csv('/tmp/foo.csv', index=False)
```

The exported csv looks like this:

```
a,b,c
1,3,
,2,8
5,,
,0,2
```

Comment: @jezrael quoting from a comment by the OP: "I need that file in .txt as a model input, that model reads a space as a value and gives error."

Comment: @suvayuI it doesn't solve the problem :( I need it without any space

Comment: There **is** no space! Maybe you mean something else?  Could you please edit the question, and provide an example of how you need it to be? Not the dataframe, but the output file.

Comment: I have edited the question and put some part from the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way around of doing this  with boolean indexing :

### DataFrame Example:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  3 -9
1 -9  2  8
2  5 -9 -9
3 -9  0  2
```

### Result:

```
>>> df[df < 0] = ''
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  3
1     2  8
2  5
3     0  2
```

Secondly, as other already included the replace method, However i would like to add supplementary to achieve the desired , First convert your negative number to Nan and at the same time  fill the Nan Values with  `''`  to get the desired:

### Resulted output:

```
>>> df.replace(-9, np.nan).fillna('')
   a  b  c
0  1  3
1     2  8
2  5
3     0  2
```

Comment: I'm suprised replacing by `np.nan` doesn't convert the columns to `float`.  Are they converted to `object` instead?